# REACT: JSON Tree with the help of Recursion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The JSON backend guys provide me its multiple parent child so I have to put the dynamic loop to show parent child.

**JSON**

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 25,
    "slug": "mobiles",
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Mobiles"
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "slug": "mobile-phones-accessories",
    "parent_id": 25,
    "name": "Mobile Phones accessories"
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "slug": "computer-laptop",
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Computer & Laptop"
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "slug": "laptops",
    "parent_id": 27,
    "name": "Laptops"
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "slug": "mobile-phones",
    "parent_id": 26,
    "name": "Mobiles Phone"
  }
]
```

**My Function (Kindly ignore this. It's just a try but I have got 1 child parent)**

```
renderCategoriesHtml() {
  const { categories } = this.props;

  if (!categories) return false;

  const nullCat = [];
  categories.map((obj) => {
    if (obj.parent_id == null) {
      nullCat.push(obj);
    }
  });

  return nullCat.map(
    (parentCat, i) => (
      <div className="form-group" key={i}>
        <div className="checkbox" key={i}>
          <label>
            <Field
              name={`categories.${parentCat.id}`}
              component="input"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            {parentCat.slug}
          </label>
        </div>
        {
          categories.map(
            (childCat, j) => (
              parentCat.id == childCat.parent_id ?
                <div className="checkbox ml-20" key={j}>
                  <label>
                    <Field
                      name={`categories.${childCat.id}`}
                      component="input"
                      type="checkbox"
                    />
                    {childCat.slug}
                  </label>
                </div>
                : ''
            )
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

**I want this (That dynamic html i want)**

```
<ul>
  <li>mobiles</li>
  <ul>
      <li>mobile-phones-accessories</li>
      <ul>
          <li>mobile-phones</li>
      </ul>
  </ul>            
  <li>computer-laptop</li>
  <ul>
      <li>laptops</li>
  </ul>    
</ul>
```

Comment: it would help if you'd explain what the problem is and provide an executable example

Comment: The JSON backend guys provide me its multiple parent child so I have to put the dynamic loop to show parent child.

Comment: Instead of directly rendering it, first convert your json into a nested parent child format and then render the content using recursion

Comment: I already did this but not getting a proper result that why I posted here.

Comment: The question is how deeply can this be nested? Can also mobile accessories have subcategories? But to be honest to you, I would rather think about to reject this kind of data format and talk to the backend to provide some sort of already nested "tree"!

Comment: Yes, may be mobile-phones have the child. I already talked to that guys but they refused and told me to do this with recursion and the funny thing is that they told me it is easy to do recursion in PHP so why not in javascript. I have to solve this.

Comment: Okay don't want to expand this to a discussion, since it's not really related to this question. I would recommend using a 'reduce' over all categories and put the null-parent categories on top and reduce the the children into the correct parent. Please keep in mind to sort your array after null parents :) hope I can write a real answer soonish!

Comment: Can you please do this? It's really helpful for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
class TreeRender extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: JSON.parse('[{"id": 25,"slug": "mobiles","parent_id": null,"name": "Mobiles"},{"id": 26,"slug": "mobile-phones-accessories","parent_id": 25,"name": "Mobile Phones accessories"},{"id": 27,"slug": "computer-laptop","parent_id": null,"name": "Computer & Laptop"},{"id": 28,"slug": "laptops","parent_id": 27,"name": "Laptops"},{"id": 29,"slug": "mobile-phones","parent_id": 26,"name": "Mobiles Phone"}]')
  }
  getCurrent = (node) => this.state.data.filter(cNode => cNode.parent_id == node).map(cNode => (
    <ul key={`node_${cNode.id}`}>
      <li>{cNode.name}</li>
      {this.getCurrent(cNode.id)}
    </ul>
  ))

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.getCurrent(null)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e6kgksph/)

Comment: Boy loves u. Thank u so much .. !!

Comment: I posted a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349417/converting-a-multi-level-json-menu-to-a-multi-level-jsx-html-menu - though mine is using a nested JSON file rather than node ids.